# How to see if an MFC checkbox is selected

Tags: c++, mfc, checkbox

I have checked many places for the answer to this, and they recommend the way I have done it, but it doesn't seem to work for me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a check box and I would like it to enable an edit box when it is check and disable it when unchecked.

The following code is what I have created:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedCheck1()
{
    UINT nCheck = CheckBox.GetState();
    if (nCheck == BST_CHECKED)
    {
        EditBox.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
    else if (nCheck == BST_UNCHECKED)
    {
        EditBox.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        EditBox.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
```

nCheck is 520 when I run it in debug, so goes straight to the else option.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CButton's GetState gets the current state of the dialog object. What you want to be using is CButton's GetCheck.

Alternatively, you can, [as indicated on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s2z1f288%28v=vs.80%29), do a bitwise mask on the return value to get the current Check state - but GetCheck is right there, so you might as well use it.

Answer (score 12):

If you read the [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2z1f288%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on `GetState` you will see that it returns a bitmask.

This means you can't use it directly in comparisons, you have to check it like a mask:

```
if ((nCheck & BST_CHECKED) != 0)
{
    // Button is checked
}
else
{
    // Button is unchecked
}
```

However, [`GetCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f%28v=vs.100%29) might be more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0f4b88d-748f-4526-9af1-a89c18643904/detecting-if-check-box-is-checked-c?forum=vcmfcatl):

```
CButton *m_ctlCheck = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX);
int ChkBox = m_ctlCheck->GetCheck();
CString str;

if(ChkBox == BST_UNCHECKED)
  str.Format(_T("Un Checked"));
else if(ChkBox == BST_CHECKED)
  str.Format(_T("Checked"));
```

Comment: All of the answers here are in common use and work, pretty much, but this is the answer that is simply "the reason we used MFC and not raw windows controls". For example if you're using "DDX_Control" to synchronize values and so on this is really the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read the state of a checkbox named IDC_CHECK1 into a variable:

```
bool IsCheck1Checked;
```

use the following code:

```
CButton *m_ctlCheck1 = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1);
IsCheck1Checked = (m_ctlCheck1->GetCheck() == 1) ? true : false;
```